# Segmentation fault, (core dumped) when changing number of processors in lpthreads

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, pthreads

I'm getting a segmentation fault when running my code on 8 processors but it works fine for 1 and 4 processors.

I'm using the lpthread library and this is the function I execute in each thread.
If any more code is needed I can add more.

```
    void *compute_gauss(void *threadid){

  int local_row, local_norm, col;
  float multiplier;
  long tid;
  tid = (long)threadid;

  fprintf(stdout, "Thread %ld has started\n", tid);

  while (global_norm < N){

    while (global_row < N) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&global_row_lock);
      local_row = global_row;
      global_row++;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_row_lock);

      print_inputs();
      multiplier = A[local_row][global_norm] / A[global_norm][global_norm];

      for (col = global_norm; col < N; col++) {
        A[local_row][col] -= A[global_norm][col] * multiplier;
      }

      B[local_row] -= B[global_norm] * multiplier;

    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    if (tid == 0){
      global_norm++;
      global_row=global_norm+1;
    }
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier); // wait until all threads arrive
  }
}
```

Here is the calling function where I initialize barriers:

```
void gauss() {
    int norm, row, col;  /* Normalization row, and zeroing
                          * element row and col */
    int i = 0;
    float multiplier;
    pthread_t threads[procs]; //declared array of threads equal in size to # processors
    global_norm = 0;
    global_row = global_norm+1;

    printf("Computing Parallelized Algorithm.\n");

    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, procs);

    /* Gaussian elimination */
    for (i = 0; i < procs; i++){
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &compute_gauss, (void *)i);
    }

    printf("finished creating threads\n");

    for (i = 0; i < procs; i++){
      pthread_join( threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("finished joining threads\n");
    /* (Diagonal elements are not normalized to 1.  This is treated in back
   *    * substitution.)
   *       */

     fprintf(stdout, "pre back substition");
    /* Back substitution */
    for (row = N - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
      X[row] = B[row];
      for (col = N-1; col > row; col--) {
        X[row] -= A[row][col] * X[col];
      }
      X[row] /= A[row][row];
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "post back substitution");
  }
```

Comment: Okay. That's good to know.

Comment: What's the backtrace of the segfault?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to look at the backtrace. After running it it just says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" in the output

Comment: Run the program with gdb, like `gdb ./myprog`, when it crashes, type `bt` in gdb and post the output.

Comment: Alright, this is the craziest thing I've seen but it looks like when I run it through gdb it runs fine and doesn't crash, but when I try running it normally it always crashes. I have ran it twice through gdb and almost 20 times outside of gdb and it has always crashed. Any ideas?

Comment: What are `A`, `B`, and `N`?

Comment: It's obviously a race condition. Running the application under gdb changes the runtime profile such that the race condition does not occur. If you can produce a [mcve], and edit your question to include it, it's possible that someone might be able to figure it out; otherwise, I'm afraid you're the only one who has the entire source code here, and the only one who will be able to figure it out. The small fragment of the obviously much larger code base, that's shown here, is not sufficient for an authoritative answer.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm This is a function to calculate gaussian elimination. Ax=B, A is the matrix on the left, B is the matrix on the right and N is the size of A, meaning A is an N x N matrix.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I can certainly provide the calling function and a matrix generation function. However, through print statements it appears that the segmentation fault is happening inside of the compute_gauss every time, so I believe the problem is there.

Comment: If you need to protect `global_row` with a mutex when modifying it in one instance, it also has to be done in every instance. An explicit barrier is not enough. That's likely to be the race condition here.

Comment: Are you initializing `barrier` with the proper number of threads?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm In my calling function which I have now provided I give it the argument procs, which is the number of processors so yes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think so. The barrier should ensure all processors enter and leave the last statement at the same time and only one will update the value since it passes the if statement.

Comment: Hey all, Harold figured out my problem. I now added an if statement that checks if local_row >= N and break if it is.

Comment: For future reference, you can also get a backtrace from a `core` file created after a segfault: `gdb ./myprog core` then `bt`.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example how the code trespasses an array, please point out if I am wrong:

```
// suppose global_row = N - 1;
while (global_row < N) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&global_row_lock);   // thread 2 waits here, global_row is N - 1;
    local_row = global_row;                 // thread 1 is here, global_row is N - 1;
    global_row++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_row_lock);

    // when thread 2 goes here, local_row is going to be N, out of array boundary.
    multiplier = A[local_row][global_norm] / A[global_norm][global_norm];
```

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense! I forgot that a thread could get to the lock in that way. Thanks Harold!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included enough code so that I can test you program. However, I'm pretty sure that the problem is that you don't have a mutext protecting `global_norm`, `global_row` and `print_inputs()`. You need to protect them with a mutex, or you need to use an atomic increment operator.  You're not seeing the crash under the debugger because it's changing your timing.

Comment: global_norm shouldn't be the problem though because I barrier it and update it between the barrier by only 1 thread. As for global_row, it is locked as can be seen in the code and print_inputs() only prints A and B it does not write to them.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be checking the return value of pthread_barrier_wait and checking for PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD?

It's also not clear why you call pthread_barrier_wait twice.

Comment: I don't believe that's how pthread_barrier_wait works. According to the documentation it just waits until the all threads reach that point and then goes back to the state of the last init. I call it initially to prevent the global_norm from being updated for other values, and I call it afterwards to prevent other threads from running with the old global_norm and global_row value.

Comment: If you use the return value of pthread_barrier_wait, you don't have to hardcode that thread with id of zero updates the global. You should be have something like: 

rv = pthread_barrier_wait(...); if(rv == PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD) { // update globals }

If you read the docs, pthread_barrier_wait returns a value such that only one thread will get returned PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD. I'm not sure that you are guarenteed that pthread_create will create a thread with tid == 0